# Why does the task size keep growing when using updateStateByKey?

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wrote a simple function to use with updateStateByKey in order to see if the problem was because of my updateFunc. I think it must be due to something else. I am running this on --master local[4].

```
val updateFunc = (values: Seq[Int], state: Option[Int]) => {
  Some(1)
}

val state = test.updateStateByKey[Int](updateFunc)
```

After a while, there are warnings, and the task size keeps increasing.

WARN TaskSetManager: Stage x contains a task of very large size (129 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

WARN TaskSetManager: Stage x contains a task of very large size (131 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

Comment: Probably your state is growing large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more and more distinct keys coming from your stream, each of which results in a new copy of `1` being added to your state.

Current updateStateByKey scan every key in every batch interval, even if there is no data for  that key. This causes the batch processing times of updateStateByKey to increase with the number of keys in the state, *even if the data rate stays fixed*.

There is a [proposal to solve this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2629).